# how to redirect users after completing a embedded google form

Tags: html, forms, redirect, submit, google-forms

I have embedded a google form in one of my pages and it will collect the users :
firstname , lastname and email address. 
but once the user submits the form. They will be redirected to the confirmation page after submitting the form.

How do I redirect the completion of the form on 'submit' to another html page? not a php file?
Thanks

Comment: I have found out that this is what i required.
http://sneakysheep.com/google-docs-form-tool-version-2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use my this man: 
Hope it help

```
      <script>
      var dynamic = 'http://www.google.com';
      </script>

      <input type="submit" value = "submit" target="_blank" onclick="window.open(dynamic)" >
```

Comment: thanks! but I have already found out how to do this really really easily. haha

Comment: hahah just vote up :D I just answer it anyway